# JPA @ManyToOne - I don't want cascade delete

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have two JPA entities: an User which can have multiple AuthTokens. The User has no references to its AuthTokens, but rather the AuthToken has a reference to its User.
Looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class AuthenticationToken {
  @Id
  private String value;

  @ManyToOne
  private User user;

  ...
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I have to delete ALL users from the database, then re-import from somewhere and insert them with the same ID as before. And, the AuthTokens should be kept, and their "user" property should be valid again.
However I get the following exception when I try to delete the users (before re-importing them):

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I'm using a MySQL database. What is the problem? Should I approach the problem in some other way?

**Update:**
This's the exception I get:

```
    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:519)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
    at hu.cargolink.backend.spreadsheets.SpreadsheetImportService.doJob(SpreadsheetImportService.java:62)
    at hu.cargolink.backend.utils.AsyncService$1.run(AsyncService.java:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cargolink`.`authentication_token`, CONSTRAINT `FK_qtxnyq3pcsdqce9fiyw0hq6es` FOREIGN KEY (`sofor_id`) REFERENCES `sofor` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 31 more
```

**Update2:**
My User entity in the above stack trace is actually called "Sofor", but I thought it doesn't matter.

**Update3:**
I've enabled auto-creation of tables this way:

```
@Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
```

**Update4:**
Eventually I had to apply a barbarian workaround: I'm storing the id of the referenced entity. :-( But I still think this's not a real solution.

Comment: When you say "sometimes I have to delete ALL users from the database" ... how are you accomplishing this? is it via java code, db trigger, script, etc?

Comment: Via Java code. Actually I call deleteAll() on a Spring repository and it fails with the exception I mentioned.

Comment: Off topic: Nice surname

Comment: IMO that "delete all the users" requirement sounds horribly wrong. I'd rather think that sometimes you want to import users and either insert new ones or -update existing ones-.

Comment: Yes, but I think this's the simplest solution if I want to have no less and no more users than I imported.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the association like this:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=true)
```

If you do so, be sure that your code handles the case where AuthenticationToken.getUser() == null;

Comment: you need to let your persistence provider and schema generator that the user can be null. If you ran your old code to generate the DB schema, and didn't update it, you'll have to manually remove the FK reference

Comment: I've tried to re-create the whole database after the modification you suggested, but it's still throwing the same exception :-(

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml file? If so, what is the value of this properpty: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60017/discussion-between-zmf-and-aron-nemmondommegavezeteknevem).

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, you have in your table:

- `tokens` that reference `user`
- you truncate or delete all from the table `user`
- it does not work because there are foreign key violations

Then, you can simply ignore those foreign key in the import script: http://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DELETE FROM users where id > 45;
INSERT INTO ...
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

You can also use Mysql workbench to create a dump of your database, which will also disable those keys. You could then adapt the dump to your case.

Note that it is independent to your modeling.

Comment: Do you know how could I do it in Spring Data?

Comment: With Spring Data, you can execute native SQL: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#d0e2010